# Vertical space before vbox

Tags: spacing, plain-tex

Note: I'm using plain TeX

I'm trying to create a layout for theatrical plays that shows stage directions aligned to the right.

I had to enclose the directions in a `\vbox` to prevent them from being split across pages. My problem is that I'm not getting the correct vertical spacing (I want `\parskip`) before the `\vbox`, only after.

I could insert a `\vskip` inside the `\vbox`, but that would cause problems when the directions block is at the top of the page. How do I get my spacing right? Thanks!

```
\parindent 0pt
\parskip8pt

\long\def\stage[#1]{
    \par
    \vbox{
        \hsize=6in
        \leftskip2.5in
        \parindent10pt
        \hfill
        {\it #1}
    }
}

\long\def\says #1:#2|{
    \bgroup
    \hskip-1in
    \vbox{\hsize=0.75in\hfill #1:}
    \hsize5.5in
    \leftskip1in
    \vskip-20pt
    #2\par
    \egroup}

\says Man: This is a rather odd problem to have, I'm not sure what to do with it.|

\says Chorus: Look behind you! You'll find it there!|

\stage [The man spins wildly in his chair]

\says Man: I don't see anything. Anything at all!|

\bye
```

Comment: `\stage` usage is wrong in your example -- `\stage<foo>` is meant rather, I think

Comment: `\vbox` doesn't start a paragraph, so you don't get `\parskip` glue.  Just do `\par\vskip\parskip\vbox{...}`. As an aside, I find the definition of `\says` very peculiar. Wouldn't `\hbox to0.75in{\hfil #1:}` be simpler than using a `\vbox`?

Comment: May be you have that in mind, but remember that you can delimit the arguments by a `\par`, so you wouldn't need `|` which seems rather awkward (i.e. `\long\def\says#1:#2 \par{..}`), just in case you didn't consider that. The `\stage [..]` seems more natural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `\vbox` doesn't start a paragraph, so `\parskip` glue is not added.

```
\parindent 0pt
\parskip8pt

\long\def\stage[#1]{
    \par\nobreak\vskip\parskip
    \vbox{
        \hsize=6in
        \leftskip2.5in
%        \parindent10pt %%% What for???
        \hfill
        \it #1\par
    }
}

\long\def\says #1:#2|{
    \par
    {
    \hskip-1in
    \hbox to 0.75in{\hfil #1:}
    \hsize5.5in
    \leftskip1in
    \vskip-20pt
    #2\par
    }
}

\says Man: This is a rather odd problem to have, I'm not sure what to do with it.|

\says Chorus: Look behind you! You'll find it there!|

\stage [The man spins wildly in his chair]

\says Man: I don't see anything. Anything at all!|

\bye
```

I changed some bits of code. In particular

```
\vbox{\hsize=0.75in\hfill #1:}
```

should be

```
\hbox to 0.75in{\hfil #1:}
```

Simpler and more efficient. The setting of `\parindent` in `\stage` is meaningless, in my opinion. On the other hand, if the directive is long, the effect will be quite peculiar.

[image]